# python matplotlib subplot I have a ylimit problem in my subplot it doesn't show first bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make 2 bar charts on the same plot with two different y axis

here my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f=open("semiv3bar.csv","r")
f=f.readlines()

f29=f[29].split('"')
f30=f[30].split('"')

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

h = [0,3]
h2 = [1,4]

ax1.bar(h,[f29[1],f29[3]],width=1,color='blue')
ax2.bar(h2,[f30[1],f30[3]],width=1,color='red')

ax1.set_xlabel('Banc 3 / Banc 4')
ax1.set_ylabel('TMG', color='b')
ax2.set_ylabel('vitesse de germination', color='r')

plt.show()
```

and it makes:

[image: it's make this]

normally I must have another bar chart in the left but it doesn't show it
because of the `ylim`

Comment: What exactly is the problem, I don't understand. You have two y-axes and are getting two bars which you plotted. How do you expect the output to be? What is `f29` and `f30`. Are their magnitudes different by several orders? In that case you can use `ax1.set_yscale("log")` to have a logarithmic left y-axis to show the smaller height bar

Comment: i want a bar of f29[1] of heigth and f30[1] of heigth in left and f29[3] and f30[3] of heigth in right

Comment: and i can't see the left bar

it doesn't work with ax1.set_yscale('log')

Comment: You are then using wrong commands: You should use a`x1.bar(h,[f29[1],f30[1]],width=1,color='blue')` and `ax2.bar(h2,[f29[3],f30[3]],width=1,color='red')`. You switched the values you want to plot

Comment: it's worth like that.